# How to drop all columns with the same name (tidyverse or base R)?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

My dataset has several columns with the same name and I'd like to delete them.

Unfortunately, `select(data, -Offender)` doesn't work (`Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name`), but I can't use `janitor::clean_names` to overcome that either—I need the remaining to column names unchanged.

I tried with base R (`df1 <- subset(df1, select = -c(Offender))`), but it then renames the other Offenders.#

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))`.

Comment: I figured it out, see answer below :)

Comment: Maybe `make.names(names(df1), unique = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a base solution.

```r
# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(runif(10), runif(10), runif(10), runif(10))
names(df) <- c("foo", "bar", "bar", "bar")

# Examine data
print(df)
#>          foo       bar       bar        bar
#> 1  0.4126322 0.1436917 0.4870304 0.80514914
#> 2  0.1642798 0.7948858 0.7741611 0.64353516
#> 3  0.6485090 0.6607900 0.9260459 0.75226835
#> 4  0.5254531 0.5535233 0.5746025 0.07131740
#> 5  0.1367792 0.4830001 0.4947695 0.46050685
#> 6  0.9517484 0.5750567 0.2231635 0.20050668
#> 7  0.9535626 0.1362335 0.5429668 0.07581875
#> 8  0.6679136 0.5017095 0.3106441 0.02235911
#> 9  0.4489072 0.3811038 0.1922099 0.07851105
#> 10 0.7724686 0.1284880 0.4240226 0.44462081

# Remove all columns called "bar"
df[, "bar" == names(df)] <- NULL

# Examine data again
print(df)
#>          foo
#> 1  0.4126322
#> 2  0.1642798
#> 3  0.6485090
#> 4  0.5254531
#> 5  0.1367792
#> 6  0.9517484
#> 7  0.9535626
#> 8  0.6679136
#> 9  0.4489072
#> 10 0.7724686
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Love it—short and sweet.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out as I finished typing the question:

1. Use the base R command `df1 <- subset(df1, select = -Offender)` to rename all the `Offenders`, leaving the other columns untouched.
2. Then use `select_at(vars(-starts_with("Offender")))` and Bob's your uncle.

In short:

```
df1 <- subset(df1, select = -Offender) %>%
  select_at(vars(-starts_with("Offender")))
```

Essentially, base R won't complain that columns have the same name and will silently fix it for you. At that point, you can `tidyverse` to your heart's content.

Comment: No need to use `c(…)` if you only have a single value. And if you use `select_at` then the `subset` command before that is redundant. Furthermore, the whole thing can be simplified to `df1 = select(df1, - starts_with("Offender"))`

Comment: `select_at` won't work when there are duplicate column names; `subset` won't complain and append numbers to the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all columns named Offender, I think there is an easier and more elegant way:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  dplyr::select(-starts_with("Offender"))
```

If that is not what you want, maybe a minimal example would help to better illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't work, as I mentioned in the question—you'll get `Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name.`

Comment: Oh, now I see it. Then Lyngbakr's answer is what you need. Can't make it simpler than that. ;)